# OpenSSH server only listen to specific hostname

Tags: ssh, openssh

Let's say I have 2 A records pointing at my domain, example.com and ssh.example.com
I can currently SSH into my server by using either domain since my OpenSSH server is listening on 0.0.0.0.
Is it possible to restrict my OpenSSH server to only listen to ssh.example.com?
I'm using Ubuntu Server 16.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Is it possible to restrict my OpenSSH server to only listen to ssh.example.com?**

AFAIK no.

This is because the client resolves ssh.example to an IP-address before contacting the server and, unlike HTTP, the SSH protocol does not have headers that specify the server hostname.

Consequently the server has no idea what server-name was provided to the client.

The server host key is used to associate a server hostname with its credentials but some SSH clients simply prompt the user to accept the key or not. This isn't (so far as I know) really a mechanism for the server to enforce how it is initially identified to the client.

This actually has nothing to do with listening on 0.0.0.0 unless the server has two IP-addresses and you configured DNS to resolve each hostname to a separate IP-address (which maybe you should do to achieve what you want)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately my ISP does not allow me to buy IP addresses.